# How to add XSRF header for REST Request from feathers client

Tags: feathersjs

I have configured Server/Node for as per [Can feathers co exist with routs managed out side of feathers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713546/can-feathers-co-exist-with-routs-managed-out-side-of-feathers). My configuration look like as follows.

```
const app = express(feathers());

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(csrf({cookie: true}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json({strict: false, limit: '1mb'}));

app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(primus({transformer: 'uws'}, primus => {
    // primus.library();
    // primus.save(__dirname + '/feathers-primus-client.js');

    primus.authorize(function (req, done) {
    const userToken = socketUtility.getTokenFromHandshake(req);

    if (csrf.verifyCSRFToken(req)) { // csrfToken === req.query.csrf;
        done();
    } else {
        done({statusCode: 403, message: 'handshake unauthorized'});
    }
});

// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
app.hooks(appHooks);
```

Here is part of my Client Code:

```
this.restFeathersClient = feathers();
this.socketFeathersClient = feathers();
this.serverAddress = `${window.location.origin}:${window.location.port}`;

const rest = feathers.rest(this.serverAddress);
this.restFeathersClient.configure(rest.fetch(window.fetch));

const socket = new Primus(this.serverAddress);
this.socketFeathersClient.configure(feathers.primus(socket));
```

Existing app is using csrf package.So without going into too much details. From the client, I need to:

1. set 'X-XSRF-COOKIE' request header on REST calls.
2. add request.query.csrf on each.

For primus our current implementation listens for "outgoing::url".

I'd appreciate any help as I am not sure how to do this with Feathers Client.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find a solution for REST calls. I am planning to use fetch, so my solution will only work for fetch. I used 'fetch-intercept' package and registered an interceptor to add the header. If you are in angularjs then you probably would be able to use $http and that would add the header. For other REST options you may have to find similar solution.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import * as fetchIntercept from 'fetch-intercept';

fetchIntercept.register({
    request(url, config) {
        if (config.method !== 'GET') {
            const XSRF_TOKEN = 'XSRF-TOKEN';
            const csrfToken = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )' + XSRF_TOKEN + '=([^;]+)'));
            if (csrfToken) {
                config.headers[`X-${XSRF_TOKEN}`] = csrfToken[2];
            }
        }
        return [url, config];
    }
});
```

Here is a solution for Primus:

```
const csrfToken = 'get your token';
const socket = new Primus(`${this.serverAddress}?csrf=${csrfToken}`);

feathersClient.configure(feathers.primus(socket));
```